# MGLRasterTileSource is drawn above MGLOverlay or below other unwanted layers. How do I get the z-order right on this?

Tags: ios, swift, maps, mapbox-ios

I'm using Mapbox iOS SDK v6.3.0

I have an MGLOverlay on my map, but whenever I add a MGLRasterTileSource it appears above the overlay and hides it!

I have currently fixed it by randomly inserting numbers into `style.insertLayer(layer, at: x)`

- Inserting at 0 seemed to work, but once I switched to the default Streets map and then back to my custom tiles, the Streets map left some junk on top of my map.
- Inserting at 15 seemed to show my map tiles on top of everything and still below wherever the overlay is, but this seems pretty prone to crashing.

There must be a cleaner way of doing this right?

The default map styleURLs work fine, it's only my custom raster tiles where I have to manually edit the style to add sources and layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 different kinds of maps I'm loading

1. Mapbox styleURLs: These are very simple to set, as you just set the `mapView.styleURL`
2. Raster Tiles: These are more complex to add and you have call `addSource()` and `addLayer()` (or in my case `insertLayer(layer: below:)`)

My initial implementation of route lines using `MGLPolyline` worked fine on styleURL maps, but was having trouble with raster tile maps as I described in the question.

Mapbox Support (Megan, the other answer) mentioned I should try to use `MGLLineStyleLayer` instead since it is more performant and I can better control the z-order since it's in the same `style.layers` array and I can `insertLayer(below:)` (which I can't seem to use with `MGLPolyline`).

However, once I did that, the styleURL maps no longer worked, since when I switched to that style of map, it clears out all the style layers and rebuilds it!!

So to finally solve my problem I had to re-add the `MGLLineStyleLayer` (and source) every time I switch to a styleURL type of map.

A GOTCHYA! Now this does work, but for some reason I couldn't cache the `MGLLineStyleLayer` and `MGLShapeSource` and re-add it directly using `addSource` and `addLayer` from the source and layers I had cached...

I had to initialize them again from scratch or Mapbox would throw an exception that I hadn't created them right. I couldn't figure out what was wrong and this was the only thing that seemed to work.

Who knows I got way off track and there is an easier solution, but this is what is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking, have you already tried adding the raster layer and specifying the [layer it should go under](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/6.3.0/Classes/MGLStyle.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLStyle(im)insertLayer:belowLayer:)? Like this:
`style.insertLayer(rasterLayer, below: existingLayer)`

Also, I would recommend using [style layers](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/markers-and-annotations/#approach-2-use-style-layers), as these are more performant and controllable. Did you get a chance to look into the [MGLLineStyleLayer](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/6.3.0/Classes/MGLLineStyleLayer.html#/MGLLineStyleLayer) for your GPS track? Theres a tutorial on this [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/runtime-add-line/).